# Excel web app Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, excel, powerview

I am currently implementing some Powerview in excel that is used on sharepoint online. My problem is that I can't get excel web app to save automatically when something is changed in excel web app only when it is saved in the real client, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

I tried your issue and unable to reproduce it. I use an Enterprise E3 license and on my team site I have checked the default behaviour in advanced settings:

[image]

To enable editing I need to switch from viewing to editing before start:

[image]

When this is done, it works like a charm. But I don't use Power View - which I'm afraid to say isn't supported:

> You can only edit Power View sheets in Excel 2013 client.

Reference: [Power View in Excel on Office 365 or in SharePoint Server](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/power-view-in-excel-on-office-365-or-in-sharepoint-server-HA103276078.aspx)